# Fetch result based on result of another query

Tags: mysql, database

How can I fetch a result from a database, based on the results of another query, in a single query?

Ie:

Fetch -> Record -> Where ID equals -> (Fetch -> Field -> Where ID equals $variable)

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
select * from tableA where cloInAB in (select colInAB from tableB where colB = 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a join would be better than a query on the result of a subquery - something like:

```
select A.* from tableA A
join tableB B on A.colInAB = B.colInAB
where B.colB = 5
```